# Check if a request submitted to custom ForkJoinPool is processed immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, forkjoinpool

I have a list of Shipment objects, and I need to make API calls to get some info about each Shipment. I'm trying to make these network calls in parallel. So I'm using Java 8 `parallelStream()` and submitting it to a custom `ForkJoinPool` as below:

```
@Autowired
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool;
...
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    List<MyObj> myObjList = null;
    try {
        myObjList = forkJoinPool.submit(() -> shipmentList.parallelStream()
            .map(shipment -> getShipmentInfo(shipment))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).get();
        } catch (Exception e){
            ...
        }
}

public MyObj getShipmentInfo(Shipment shipment) {
    // Make network call and return MyObj
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I want to optimize the number of threads in my `ForkJoinPool`, so I need to check how it is performing. Is there anyway I can log if a request is not taken up and processed immediately by the pool?
2. My system gets a lot of traffic. So if I do a `submit()` and `get()` on an `autowired ForkJoinPool`, will my code by waiting on Shipments from different requests? What I mean is, lets say I get 2 requests in parallel. Request1 has 3 Shipments associated with it, and Request2 has 5 Shipments. So will the above code be waiting till all 8 Shipments are done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to optimize the number of threads in my ForkJoinPool, so I need to check how it is performing. Is there anyway I can log if a request is not taken up and processed immediately by the pool?

You can preiodically check if the submission queue is not empty via the `ForkJoinPool.hasQueuedSubmissions()`. So if it returns true - requests are not taken up and processed immediately. Potentially you could catch such a moment even if it's ok, so you could double-check that the queue size is small with `ForkJoinPool.getQueuedSubmissionCount()` (note it has an O(n) time-complexity where n is the number of queued submissions though).

> My system gets a lot of traffic. So if I do a submit() and get() on an autowired ForkJoinPool, will my code by waiting on Shipments from different requests? What I mean is, lets say I get 2 requests in parallel. Request1 has 3 Shipments associated with it, and Request2 has 5 Shipments. So will the above code be waiting till all 8 Shipments are done?

Yes, it will wait till all 8 Shipments are done. Depending on the pool and queue size, in the best case it will take approximately the same amount of time the longest Shipment processing took.